# Conditional Distribution: how to set up Limit of Integration of a joint density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have a question in conditional probability. I'm asked to find the conditional distribution, however, I'm unsure about the answer given and would appreciate someone helping straighten out the theory behind it.

*Question is from: "A First Course in Probability 9th ed; Sheldon Ross" p.274, Problem 6.42.
It asks: The joint density of X and Y is $f(x,y)=c(x^2-y^2)e^{-x}$,
and $0\le x\lt \infty, -x\le y\le x$. 
I am to find the conditional distribution of $Y$, given $X=x$.*

I first solved my $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$, which is $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac34\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^3}$.

To get the distribution, I need to solve for $F_{Y|X}(y|x)=P(Y\epsilon(-x,x)|X=x)$.

**Here is where I get stuck.**

The answer given shows that I need to integrate from -x to y... If you're integrating with respect to dy, are you allowed to put y in your limits of integration? I'll type it out so it's clear:

$F_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac3{4x^3}\int_{-x}^{y}(x^2-y^2)dy$

The final calculation from here is elementary, but like I mentioned, how does this make sense conceptually. Integrating with respect to y doesn't make sense by putting y in the integral...

Thank you kindly in advance.

edit: 1. original equation was changed from + to -, (typo). 
2. A change of index was suggested $F_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac3{4x^3}\int_{-x}^{y}(x^2-t^2)dt$, but I'm still wondering why the integral is not from (-x,x) instead of now (-x,y).

Comment: Why is $x^2+y^2$ in $f(x,y)$ becoming $x^2-y^2$ in $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$? // Why is giving $f_{Y|X}$ not sufficient to answer the question "Find the conditional distribution"?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was a typo. The other calculations are correct.

Comment: $f_{Y|X}$ is the conditional PDF. Whereas the book defines conditional distribution function of Y given that $X=x$ is: $F_{Y|X}(a|x)=P[Y\le a |X=x]=\int_\infty^a f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy$

Comment: Not sure I get your point. Recall that a distribution is fully characterized either by its CDF or, when its PDF exists, by its PDF. Hence the PDF is *at least* as qualified as the CDF to describe a given distribution. Actually, except in some introductory probability classes, mathematicians use PDFs rather than CDFs (as soon as the PDF exists, of course).

Comment: I understand what you mean now. I was under the impression that I needed to show the Conditional Cumulative dist. fn. What you're saying is my answer is done at my "f" step, since that is a pdf for my conditional distribution. I was confusing "distribution" with being the same as the "cumulative distribution". So what you're saying is a distribution is characterized also by the probability density fn as well?

Comment: Indeed (provided the PDF exists). And densities are so easier to interpret... :-)

Comment: Given that that is cleared up (thank you), could you please elucidate why our CDF calculation would choose an upper bound of y instead of x? I get that the lower bound is -x.

Comment: Why, because $F_{Y|X}(y|x)=P(Y\leqslant y|X=x)$ hence the integral is on $(-\infty,y)$. And in your case the density is zero except on $(-x,x)$ hence the integral goes from $-x$ to $y$ provided $-x\leqslant y\leqslant x$ (if $y\lt-x$, integral zero, if $y\gt x$, integral from $-x$ to $x$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track for the conditional density function.   $f_{Y\mid X} = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$

(I haven't checked you integration for the marginal, but it eyeballs right.)

The cumulative density function is $F_{Y|X}(y|x)=P(Y\in(-x,\color{blue}{y})|X=x) = \mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X=x)$

---

The other thing is that statements like $\displaystyle\int_{c}^{y} g(y)\operatorname dy = G(y)-G(c)$ are a *slight* abuse of notation that is unfortunately fairly commonly used.

With a change of index, the definite integral is identical to: $\displaystyle\int_c^y g(t)\operatorname d t = G(y)-G(c)$

So you have: $$\begin{align} F_{Y|X}(y|x) & = \frac3{4x^3}\int_{-x}^{y}(x^2-y^2)dy
\\[2ex] & = \frac3{4x^3}\int_{-x}^{y}(x^2-t^2)dt \end{align}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Let me suggest to *avoid* the abuse of notation in your own answer (at line -3).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The final calculation is very straightforward. I was wondering if you could elaborate more on why we are choosing $Y\epsilon (-x,y)$ and not sticking with our $(-x,x)$ from the question. The answer looks a little odd with x's and y's left behind when we know y is between -x to x.

Comment: @sahimat Just as $F_Y(y) = \mathsf P(Y\leq y)$, then so to does $F_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X=x)$.